# Creating a MySQL Database Using a Variable in a BASH Script

Tags: mysql, database, bash

I'm trying to create a MySQL database using a variable in a BASH script. Here is the code giving me trouble:  **database="mysql --verbose --user=root --password --execute="create database foo""** When run it fails with an option listing. I'm sure the issue is with the use of quotes after the execute option but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: use different quotes: `database="... --execute='create database foo'"`

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of setting the `database` variable?

```
mysql --verbose --user=root --password --execute="create database foo"
```

Should work just fine for creating the database `foo`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql --verbose --user=root --password --execute="create database $1"
```

save it in your bashscript folder and run it like:

```
nameofbashscript mydatabasename
```